# C++ regex unhandled exception (ES regex object)

Tags: c++, regex, std, throw, unhandled-exception

I've read that by default C++ uses ES spec for creating regex objects.

Following regex would work in javascript and match anything delimited by unescaped square brackets:

```
std::regex (R"((?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\]))");
```

But throws an unhandled exception in C++.

What's wrong?

Comment: It depends which browser you used. C++ only supports ES5, not ES2018 as Chrome now does. Besides, there are differences between C++ and JS ES5 implementations.

Comment: oh, so I guess it's the positive lookbehind's fault?

Comment: Yes, use `std::regex (R"(\[([^\]\[]*)\])");`

Comment: This doesn't match strings with escaped square brackets in them

Comment: But your regex does not match them either. Post the sample string and expected output.

Comment: Something like`[my \[ value]` wouldn't work

Comment: You're correct, doesn't work for `[my \[ value\] ]`

Comment: Are you extracting those substrings? Are there 1 or more matches per string? Please share the whole relevant code.

Comment: My matching process works fine with other expressions, it's now just about finding the right regex without lookbehinds to match the whole `[my \[ value \] \\]` (last bracket isn't escaped because it's followed by two slashes

Comment: Hej, so did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use a lookbehind in C++ `std::regex` pattern even with the default regex flavor because it is based on the ECMAScript specs older than ECMAScript 2018 used in the current Chrome browser where you [may use lookbehinds](http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html#lookbehind-assertions) with patterns of unlimited length.

**MSVC C++ regex ECMAScript flavor** is yet more demanding to special char escaping: the `]` char must ALWAYS be escaped.

To extract substrings inside two unescaped square brackets that may contain escape sequences you may use

```
std::regex reg(R"((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*\[([^\][\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\][\\]*)*)\])");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFpMX7/2). **NOTE**: It does not support nested unescaped square brackets.

**Details**

- `(?:^|[^\\])` - a non-capturing group
- `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more repetitions of double backslash
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\][\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\]\[\\]*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\][\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[` and `\`
  - `(?:\\[\s\S][^\][\\]*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `\\[\s\S]` - a `\` char followed with any char
    - `[^\][\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`, `[` and `\`
- `\]` - a `]` char.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/VKTBtH):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::regex reg(R"((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*\[([^\][\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\][\\]*)*)\])");
    std::string s("Some text [my \\[ value \\] here] and here");
    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_search(s, matches, reg)) {
        std::cout<<matches.str(1);                 // => my \[ value \] here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @MateuszSowiński It was an unescaped `]` in the pattern. It is really a weird requirement as  `]` is never special in any regex flavor I know.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński `]` is not a special char outside a bracket expression in almost all flavors.